# Haskell - GADTs pattern match with class constraints

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, gadt

Consider the following example

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs #-}
data Phantom = A | B
data Foo (a :: Phantom) where
  FooA :: Foo 'A
  FooB :: Foo 'B
class PhantomConstraint (a :: Phantom)
instance PhantomConstraint 'A -- Note: No instance for 'B
someFunc :: PhantomConstraint a => Foo a -> ()
someFunc FooA = ()
```

If I do something like this GHC complains that the pattern matches are inexhaustive for `someFunc`, however, if I do try and include the case for FooB (which I don't want to do for domain specific reasons) it complains that it can't deduce the instance of `PhantomConstraint` for `Foo 'B`

Is there any way to make GADT pattern matching aware of typeclass constraints such that it eliminates required arms of pattern matching?

EDIT: More details around what I want to do. I have a bucket of types that are all somewhat related but have different properties. In the OO world this is what people use subtyping and inheritance for. However in the FP community, the consensus seems to be that there is no real good way to do subtyping, so in this case I need to hack around it. As such I have a GADT that unifies all of the types, but with different parameters on that type. I then proceed to write different typeclasses and typeclass instances on the type parameters (enabled by datakinds, no term representation). I want to be able to express that some of these types from the datakinds have a property that others don't, but they all do share certain common properties so I don't really want to break up the type. The only other option I can foresee is to create a taxonomy on the type part, but then the DataKinds types get messed up.

Comment: Typeclasses are *open*, that means that there is nothing preventing somebody else, in another module, from adding an `instance PhantomConstraint 'B`, thus making `someFunc`'s patterns inexhaustive.  There are probably ways to do what you want, but maybe some more details about your problem will help guide to a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce the issue. This loads without warnings or errors in GHCi 8.4.3.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}
{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}
module GADTwarning2 where

data Phantom = A | B

data Foo (a :: Phantom) where
  FooA :: Foo 'A
  FooB :: Foo 'B

class PhantomConstraint (a :: Phantom)

instance PhantomConstraint 'A -- Note: No instance for 'B

someFunc :: PhantomConstraint a => Foo a -> ()
someFunc FooA = ()
someFunc FooB = ()
```

As luqui explained in a comment, we can't avoid the `FooB` case, since type classes are open, and another instance could be added later on by another module, making the pattern match non exhaustive.

If you are absolutely sure you don't need any other instances except the one for `A`, you can try to use

```
class a ~ 'A => PhantomConstraint (a :: Phantom)
```

Or, if the index `a` can be `'A` or `'B`, but never a third constructor `'C`, then we can try to reify this fact:

```
class PhantomConstraint (a :: Phantom) where
   aIsAOrB :: Either (a :~: 'A) (a :~: 'B)
```

and then exploit this member later on.